# "Blood rushing to the head" during handstands: How is it regulated?

Tags: blood, exercise, headache, physiology

Many people who start practicing handstands or headstands report discomfort in their head, ranging from a mild sense of fullness to "my head is going to explode." The standard response in online communities is something like this: *The sensation is caused by blood rushing to your head, it's harmless, and it will go away with practice*. [This oft-cited blog post](http://chrissalvato.com/2013/08/handstand-exploding-head-syndrome/) is a good example.

They seem to be claiming that with exposure, the body becomes more effective at regulating changes in bloodflow that result from being inverted. If this is true, do we know what the regulatory mechanism is and how it improves?

Comment: Too broad. You're asking for a textbook in the title and three long answers in the body. If you can edit your question to just one of the three you asked it will probably be okay.

Comment: Okay, I have edited the question.

Comment: Thank you. You can always ask the other two as separate questions.

Answer (score 2):

***What happens [during inversion](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/2628633/)?***

> - increase in blood pressure
> - Oxygen uptake increase
> - Heart rate decreased significantly
> - The double product, the frequency of breaths, and tidal volume were not significantly changed

***What happens [post exercise](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/3389990/?i=2&from=/2628633/related)*** ?

> nonsignificant changes in heart rate, systolic blood pressure, and double product from the pre-inversion baseline standing position.

***What are [chronic changes](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/3190419/?i=4&from=/2628633/related)***

> No physiologic adaptations occurred in any of the inverted positions as a result of inversion training.

***Mechanism for maintenance of Blood pressure?***

There is baroreceptor at aorta and carotid sinus.
These receptors have a baroreflex mechanism that helps maintain normal pressure on the brain and other vital organs.

> As the acute adaptation and resetting are correlated using a graphic analysis, we hypothesize that the baroreceptors can recognize a new pressure level within minutes. The inherent ability incurs downward and upward adaptation as well as resetting at lower and higher holding pressure, respectively.[link](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/2376214/)
>
> It is important to note that baroreceptors adapt to sustained changes in arterial pressure. For example, if arterial pressure suddenly falls when a person stands, the baroreceptor firing rate will decrease; however, after a period of time, the firing returns to near normal levels as the receptors adapt to the lower pressure. [CV physiology](https://www.cvphysiology.com/Blood%20Pressure/BP012)

***Adaptation of carotid and aortic baroreceptors***

> the longest measure time for an almost complete adaptation of mechanoreceptors is about 2 days, which is the adaptation time for many carotid and aortic baroreceptors; however some physiologist believes that these specialised baroreceptors never fully adapt.

[excerpt from Guyton And Hall textbook of medical physiology]-

[image: excerpt from Guyton And Hall]

So, as people practice this handstand posture, slowly the receptors **may start to adapt** or they **might never adapt**

Hence, in short, we can say that the body's mechanism either remained the same or adapted a little in long term, while the short term regulation of blood pressure remained the same.

***Cerebral blood flow***

With the regulation of BP in mind, we can think further about the regulation of cerebral blood flow.

> cerebral blood flow is autoregulated extremely well between the arterial pressure limits of 60 mm Hg and 140 mm Hg; further, the cerebral blood flow autoregulation occurs even when the mean arterial pressure Rises to as high as 160 - 180 mm as in case of hypertensive

[Ref. Guyton and Hall Physiology]-
[image: 7]]

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE. We work differently to most SE sites, where we have a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) so that the answer can be independently verified, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help] or [meta]. Unreferenced claims can lead to answers being deleted.

Comment: Okay Chris I understand, I'll add references

Comment: Good answer. I'd just note, adaptation of the baroreceptors, which you spend a good deal of space on, would be the opposite of the adaptation the OP seems to be asking about. A baroreceptor that adapts to a higher pressure during an inversion, would allow higher blood pressure in the cerebral vessels, making it **less** effective at regulating changes, rather than more. I'd suggest leaving the paragraphs on baroreceptor adaptation out of this answer, since it's directed at a different question.

Comment: I'd also suggest converting your image of text to a block quote. Text in images can't be found in a search, and increase the page load time.

Comment: @DeNovo The images appear to be photos from a textbook. Although they could be converted to text using an OCR service, which are available free on the web, that's not something most people would be familiar with. The underlining and notes on the first photo will also make OCR problematic. If OP wants to do as you recommend, I suggest onlineocr.net (just because I've used it and it works, no personal connection).

Comment: @CareyGregory I just meant type it in as a block quote instead of attaching a picture.

Comment: @DeNovo Adaptation of baroreceptors would be towards normalisation Blood pressure. This would cause an increase in firing rate (condition, if only they adapt) and this would cause decreased blood pressure normally. So setpoint is low and this is the adaptation I'm talking about. So if pressure now increases during inversions it would increase to a lesser level as before adaptation. For searchability, I had written important lines in the block, the pic was just for reference (as the textbook might have a different edition in future) otherwise should I provide ISBN number instead?

Comment: I'm sorry, but you are wrong. The carotid baroreceptor, as part of the afferent limb of blood pressure regulation, provides information to the vasomotor center in the medulla. Increased pressure in the carotid sinus leads to changes in autonomic outflow, the efferent limb. If that afferent limb adapts to increased blood pressure, the efferent response is decreased. Regardless of the encoding (in terms of firing rate), adaptation of the afferent limb results in decreased outflow via the efferent limb.

Comment: So a baroreceptor response that has adapted to a higher pressure results in a weaker reduction in pressure. I don't doubt that this doesn't happen during inversion training, but it does happen in hypertensive disease. It's the pathophysiologic mechanism for cerebrovascular disease. The point here is that a baroreceptor that adapts to higher blood pressure doesn't lead to lower blood pressure in cerebral vessels, it leads to higher blood pressure in the cerebral vessels.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I'm sorry I was thinking incorrectly by thinking of aerobic exercises decreasing blood pressure, but those might be due to different mechanisms. I'll edit the answer. Good point, Thanks :)

Comment: @De Novo, where should I edit? I understand that you are correct about hypertensive patients and that would be opposed to what OP is asking. But does same thing applies to inversion training?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure. The more carefully I look at this answer, the less I think it  clearly answers the question. The main part that I appreciated was the link to the study that demonstrated no physiologic adaptation to blood pressure and cardiorespiratory fitness after inversion training. The best I can suggest is reworking your answer to focus on that. That's only my personal suggestion.